# Определить количество случаев соответствия слоговому принципу графики

Tags: русская-графика

Определите количество случаев соответствия слоговому принципу графики. Укажите случаи отступления от слогового принципа графики.

щавель жизнь чаща цифра шёлк парашют межимпериалистическая щука жюри бульон

Comment: @elenaalisa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соответствий - 16.

**щавель** - ща - отступление: за буквой, обозначающей мягкий согласный, следует буква, обозначающая гласный непереднего ряда; вель - в соответствии со слоговым принципом.

**жизнь** – отступление:  за буквой, обозначающей твердый согласный, следует буква, обозначающая гласный переднего ряда.

**чаща** – отступление в обоих слогах.

**цифра** - циф - отступление, ра - соответствие.

**шёлк** - отступление.

**парашют** - па, ра – соответствие, шют - отступление.

**межимпериалистическая** - ме - соответствие; жим - отступление (после твёрдого Ж должен быть Ы); пе-ри-а-ли-сти - соответствие; че - соответствие; ска-я - соотв.

**щука** - щу - отступление; ка - соответствие.

**жюри** – жю - отступление; ри - соответствие.

**бульон** - бу - соответствие; льон - отступление.